# One user.conf file for all app versions

Tags: c#, .net, config

In my project I'm using a setting files and I have some fields that have "User" scope. So `/AppData/Local/MyCompany/MyApp.exe_Url_wkjotpgbovnyqkbwotylz/0.0.2.2(my app version)/user.conf` file contains that fields.

As far as I understood this folder was created automatically and its name was based on my applicaton version.

Is there any way to create user.conf file regardless of the program version?

Answer (score 0):

You can always roll your own!

I've done this in the past by creating a class to store settings using both .NET's built-in [XML serialization techniques](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/182eeyhh%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) or use [JSON](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb410770%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) or [.NET's built-in JSON stuff][3] (json.org can also be a great resource).

Here's an example using .NET's JSON:

**Create a settings class:**

```
[DataContract]
    class Settings
    {
        [DataMember]
        internal string food;

        [DataMember]
        internal int bar;
    }
```

**Read/Write code:**

```
Settings s = new Settings();
MemoryStream stream1 = new MemoryStream();
DataContractJsonSerializer ser = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(Settings));

// Write the settings
ser.WriteObject(stream1, s);

// Read settings
Person p2 = (Person)ser.ReadObject(stream1);
```